# why is my struct not defined? Queue in C

Tags: c, struct, queue

I need a really simple queue for a FIFO operation:
I already worked with structs so I used some old code that i modified for my purpose: but now my compiler doesn't accept Node as a struct and i got some incompatible pointer issues. Hope someone sees something I'm missing:

CODE:

```
typedef struct _Node {
    Node*   next;
    Task*   element;
} Node;

typedef struct _Queue {
    Node*   head;
} Queue;

Queue* createQueue() {
    Queue* q = (Queue*) calloc(1,sizeof(Queue));
    return q;
} 

void enqueue(Queue* q, Task* task){
    Node* newTask = (Node*) calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    newTask->element = task;
    Node* root = q->head;
    Node* next = root->next;
    if (q) {
        while(next) {
            root = next;
            next = root->next;
        }
        root->next = newTask;
    }
}

Task* dequeue(Queue* q) {
    Node* root = q->head;
    Task* topTask = NULL;
    if(q && root) {
        topTask = root->element;
        q->head = root->next;
        free(root);
    }
    return topTask;
}
```

ERRORS:

```
.6:2: error: unknown type name ‘Node’
  Node* next;
  ^
 In function ‘enqueue’:
:23:15: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  Node* next = root->next;
               ^
c:27:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    next = root->next;
         ^
c:29:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   root->next = newTask;
              ^
c: In function ‘dequeue’:
c:38:11: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   q->head = root->next;
```

Thx in advance,

Tim4497

Comment: When you declare the field `Node*   next;`, the compiler does not know about type named `Node`. It knows only `struct Node`.

Comment: @Eugene he typedefed the strutct so it should know about just Node.

Comment: @Fredrik It is happening *after* the field declaration.

Comment: Yup that just worked out everything... thank you :) but im curious because I used it without struct and it worked?

Comment: Ah you are right.

Comment: @Tim4497 Perhaps you had `typedef struct Node Node;` before that. Or used C++ compiler, which (not sure) is allowing this.

Comment: Ahh okay I got it :)